# Why ROUND function doesn't work with Big decimal data?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to do a conditional test given as :

```
S0 = FILTER E1ECPRA BY ((NO_PCI != '0') AND (ROUND(MT_DVS) != 0) AND (ROUND(MT_EUR) != 0));
```

Where **MT_EUR** and **MT_DVS** are big decimal data.

Firstly they are defined as :

```
E1ECPRA = FOREACH E1ECPRA_BRUT GENERATE
    MT_DVS           AS    MT_DVS,
    MT_CVE           AS    MT_EUR;
```

where MT_CVE and MT_DVS are bigdecimal also.

The problem is :

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ROUND
>   as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

How can I resolve this problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like ROUND works on float and double.You could probably use [ROUND_TO()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ROUND_TO.html)  and compare it to 0.0.Something like ROUND_TO(MT_CVE,0) = 0.0